# How do you enable short-tag syntax in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, syntax, codeigniter-2

I have an app (CodeIgniter) that uses the

```
<?=$variable?>
```

syntax instead of

```
<?php echo $variable; ?>
```

and I would like for it to work on my local host. What is it that I need to enable in my php.ini file to do this?

Please note, I am not asking how to enable short_open_tag, but how to enable this in CodeIgniter.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Really RTFM: "NOTE: This directive also affect the `<?=` shorthand prior to PHP 5.4.". -1 for not actually reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In CodeIgniter's `config.php`:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Rewrite PHP Short Tags
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your PHP installation does not have short tag support enabled CI
| can rewrite the tags on-the-fly, enabling you to utilize that syntax
| in your view files.  Options are TRUE or FALSE (boolean)
|
*/
$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;
```

This will also mean that it isn't host dependent.

Answer (score 3):

Read on this: [PHP Short Open Tag: Convenient Shortcut or Short Changing Security?](http://perishablepress.com/php-short-open-tag/)

Comment: Thanks. That was interesting.

Answer (score 3):

1. Search for php.ini file in your php installed directory
2. open it by any text editor then just you search again "short_open_tag" if you find that line like ";short_open_tag = Off" then just remove the ";" and restart your apache server it will work. But I highly request you not to use php short tag due to not all the web server accept the php short tag.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if the short form tags were enabled on the server. This would prevent CodeIgniter to rewrite your tags.

Locate your PHP.ini file in your PHP installation directory. Search for "short_open_tag". You will see it referenced a number of times under the "Language Options". Locate the uncommented one and change it to on.

The INI would look like this:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Language Options ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Enable the PHP scripting language engine under Apache.
; http://php.net/engine
engine = On

; This directive determines whether or not PHP will recognize code between
; <? and ?> tags as PHP source which should be processed as such. It's been
; recommended for several years that you not use the short tag "short cut" and
; instead to use the full <?php and ?> tag combination. With the wide spread use
; of XML and use of these tags by other languages, the server can become easily
; confused and end up parsing the wrong code in the wrong context. But because
; this short cut has been a feature for such a long time, it's currently still
; supported for backwards compatibility, but we recommend you don't use them.
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: Off
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/short-open-tag
;short_open_tag = Off
; XAMPP for Linux is currently old fashioned
 short_open_tag = On
```