# Codeigniter cant display image

Tags: php, codeigniter

I cant display image in code igniter.
What's going wrong?

```
<!-- Preloader -->
<div class="preloader flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <img class="animation__wobble" src="<? echo base_url();?>assets/dist/img/AdminLTELogo.png" alt="AdminLTELogo" height="60" width="60">
</div>
```

Comment: What specifically goes wrong? Is the image URL malformed or nonexistent? These might be helpful: [Codeigniter php short tags not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868084/codeigniter-php-short-tags-not-working) and [How do you enable short-tag syntax in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532925/how-do-you-enable-short-tag-syntax-in-codeigniter)

Comment: short tag on new PHP should be `<?= base_url() ?>`, avoid <? ?> as it will not supported and have clash with xml syntax.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 1):

- You must specify that you intend to use the `php` code.
- Before calling the`Base_url()` check that you have alredy set your base_url() in the `codeigniter->Application->config->config.php file`
- create a local folder within your CodeIgniter application along with the application, system, etc let's says `public` and place your image in it

Now the img tag goes like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>public/yourimage.png">
```